# Magento - Product details don't update

Tags: magento

When I try and update a product via admin, the update fails and there is no error message:

Catalogue -> Manage Products -> Edit
I change the name of a product for example

I click save.
A pop up states 'Please wait" after a couple of seconds it disappears and then the browser waits for the domain for about 60 seconds (I assume an ajax call?) and then does nothing.

Thats it.
There's nothing in the server error log.
Version: Magento ver. 1.5.0.1
Running on cPanel server.

Comment: It seems to be this ajax post that fails: https://www.domainname.com/index.php/steelbox-staff-login/catalog_product/save/id/352/key/ca01e41badca44a5e5b39198ae26cfc3/

Comment: Do any other functions in the admin NOT save after editing besides a products details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple once I had correctly diagnosed the problem -PHP post_max_size was too low and needed increasing.
And error that would have been spotted sooner if error reporting was enabled in admin area of Magneto and if the post wasn't done by AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Net tab in Firebug and look what response do you recive from the server. Looks like you forgot something like `echo 123; die;` somwhere in yor code. Anyway, the response you'll see will help you to find where the problem is located.

Comment: The status text for that POST in the Network tab returns '302
Moved Temporarily' after 42 seconds?